# trying to filter brand names but its not working

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to filter brands using search bar but I don't know the ajax code to filter

Controller

```
$brands = (request()->session()->get('business.enable_brand') == 1) ? Brands::where('business_id', $business_id)
                    ->pluck('name', 'id')
                     ->prepend(__('lang_v1.all_brands'), 'all') : false;
```

ajax

```
$(function () {

    var minlength = 3;

    $("#searchbrands").keyup(function () {
        var that = this,
        value = $(this).val();

         if (value.length >= minlength ) {
            if (searchRequest != null) 
                searchRequest.abort();
            searchRequest = $.ajax({

            });
        }
     });
 });
```

View

```
<input type="search" id="searchbrands"  name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Type brand here. . . ">

            @if(!empty($brands))

                @foreach($brands as $id => $brand)
                <a class="fontsizs text-uppercase" id="product_brand" onclick="brandfilter({{ $id }});" href="javascript:void(0)" >{{$brand}}</a>

                @endforeach
            @endif
```

Comment: Please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to pass the searched value from ajax to controller and in your controller, do the db query for searching.